# Move Div to Another Div if the date is old

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a webpage for all events, there is two section upcoming events and past events,
both section has multiple divs, if the date of the div in upcoming event is older than today, it should automatically move to past events, and should be deleted from upcoming events.

I already have a function to sort the divs in date wise

The Below snippet is one of my divs and fuction to sort.

```js
// Function to sort the events by date.

function ddmmyyyy(s) {
  var part = s.split(/\//),
    date = new Date();
  date.setYear(part[2]);
  date.setMonth(part[1] - 1);
  date.setDate(part[0]);
  return date;
}

// In Descending Order
function ddmmyyyClassSortDescending(a, b) {
  var A = ddmmyyyy(a.getAttribute("data-event-date")),
    B = ddmmyyyy(b.getAttribute("data-event-date"));
  return A < B ? 1 : -1;
}

// In Ascending Order
function ddmmyyyClassSortAscending(a, b) {
  var A = ddmmyyyy(a.getAttribute("data-event-date")),
    B = ddmmyyyy(b.getAttribute("data-event-date"));
  return A > B ? 1 : -1;
}

$.fn.sortChildren = function(cmp) {
  var self = this,
    children = $.makeArray(this.children()).sort(cmp);
  $.each(children, function(i, child) {
    self.append(child);
  });
  return self;
};

$(function() {
  $(".past-Events").sortChildren(ddmmyyyClassSortDescending);
});
```

```html
<div id="past-Events">Past Event
  <div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="distinguished-Lectures" data-event-date="15/12/2021">
    <center>
      <b>
         <h5>
             <font color="#183a1d">IMSc Distinguished Lecture</font>
         </h5>
      </b>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  How are the items added in the first place when the page loads?  Looks like they're hardcoded into the html.

Comment: Also don't use `<font>` tag, unless you are stuck in 1990. Use CSS for styling your HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi, the events are hardcoded into Html, since one or two only happening in a month, so the issue is a event will be added in the upcoming events with a data-event-date attribute, if the date is older than today it should be moved to a another section, that is past events.

Comment: @cloned Hi, I'm new to this, they gave an old website and asked for some changes, will use css for upcoming things.

Comment: Ok, reason I asked is that there's a better solution than "moving" the event - and that's rendering it in the correct place in the first place.   If they're to be on the page rather than a DB, I suggest storing the events in a json string at the top of the page (or preferably in a separate.js) - this will make it easier for you/anyone else to edit/add new ones as they wouldn't need to find the correct place, know the exact html and not break something else along the way.  Your js would then generate the html based on the data - ie *data-driven website*.

Comment: To *move* them, use jquery's [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) - easiest would be to loop through each `$("[data-event-date]")`, parse its date value (you might want to use yyyy-mm-dd to ensure the date parses correctly) then if it's `<` today, use .append to move it.